# Group vector elements

Tags: r

I have a vector

```
 [1] 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 7 7 8 8 8 8 8
```

and I want to group it by values collecting indexes, i.e., I want the data frame

```
 data.frame(value=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
            beg=c(1,3,7,10,14,17,20,22),
            end=c(2,6,9,13,16,19,21,26))
```

(or any other equivalent data structure, e.g., list of lists).

Comment: `rle` should give you enough data to build such a data frame

Answer (score 5):

Turning hrbrmstr's comment into answer

```
x <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8)
data.frame(value = rle(x)$values, 
           begin = cumsum(rle(x)$lengths) - rle(x)$lengths + 1, 
           end   = cumsum(rle(x)$lengths))

  value begin end
1     1     1   2
2     2     3   6
3     3     7   9
4     4    10  13
5     5    14  16
6     6    17  19
7     7    20  21
8     8    22  26
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the input data, finding the index of first and last observation for the grouping vector ('x') will get the result.

```
library(data.table) #data.table_1.9.5
setDT(list(x))[, list(beg=.I[1L], eng=.I[.N]), list(value=V1)]
#    value beg eng
#1:     1   1   2
#2:     2   3   6
#3:     3   7   9
#4:     4  10  13
#5:     5  14  16
#6:     6  17  19
#7:     7  20  21
#8:     8  22  26
```

But, if the vector is 'x1' and the non-continuous blocks should be regarded as separate groups (ie. 1,3), then use `rleid` which was introduced as a new feature in [v1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table)

```
 setDT(list(x1))[, list(beg=.I[1L], eng=.I[.N]), 
        list(value1=rleid(V1), value=V1)][,value1:=NULL][]
 #   value beg eng
 #1:     1   1   2
 #2:     2   3   6
 #3:     3   7   9
 #4:     4  10  13
 #5:     5  14  16
 #6:     6  17  19
 #7:     7  20  21
 #8:     3  22  24
 #9:     1  25  26
```

#### data

```
x <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7,
        8, 8, 8, 8, 8)

x1 <- x
x1[22:24] <- 3
x1[25:26] <- 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`rle` is the way to go -

this gets you most of the way...

```
x <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4 ,4 ,5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8 ,8 ,8, 8)

library(dplyr)

temp <- rle(x)

df <- data.frame(
value = temp$values,
end1 = temp$lengths
) %>%
  mutate(end = cumsum(end1),
         beg = lag(end)+1) %>%
  select(value, beg, end)
```

Just need to sub in the `1` for the first start point.

```
#  value beg end
#1     1  NA   2
#2     2   3   6
#3     3   7   9
#4     4  10  13
#5     5  14  16
#6     6  17  19
#7     7  20  21
#8     8  22  26
```